# How to resolve not working fonts in Xamarin Forms

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I want to add special font to my xamarin app. I tried to add font to my project using this [guide](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/embedded-fonts-xamarin-forms/), but still, when I`m trying to run app on my android device, font is not changed.

in xaml:
 `<Label Text="Reminder" FontSize="40" FontFamily="CabinSketch">`

in assembly info: `[assembly: ExportFont("CabinSketchBold.ttf", Alias = "CabinSketch")]`

I also added `CabinSketchBold.ttf` file to resources in my main project and android project as "Embedded Resource"

But still, font in my device is default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete app data and try again. And you only need the fontfile in your main project as embedded resource.
There is a issue about this: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/11843